# I am running into problems while using Gpush command from vim-fugitive plugin

Tags: gvim, plugin-fugitive, vim8

I have recently started using the vim-fugitive plugin, and currently I am facing problem with the Gpush command.

I tried `:Gpush %` which gives me errors in the quick fix window saying

> fatal: could not read from remote repository
>   make sure you have the correct access rights

I can push from outside vim (the terminal) without any problems.

Do I need extra configuration? or are there other arguments when executing `:Gpush` command?

I have already tried going through the help file via `:h fugitive` and could find any clue. Please help.

Comment: `:Gpush %` feels incorrect. Can you `:Gpush` without any arguments?

Comment: I have tried that too, vim stops responding as if something is happening in the background, I can't do anything afterwards, except killing the process and then restarting vim.

Comment: @PeterRincker is correct: the command is `:Gpush`. If there is background processing, it’s usually vim running git push (though with dispatch this can be off-loaded). I suspect there’s something else going on

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, is there any diagnostic command to figure out whats wrong and troubleshoot the problem?

Comment: You could try :debug Gpush (i think)

Comment: using `:debug Gpush` I get "remote: No anonymous write access. fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/my_github_username/my_remote_repo"

Comment: Is your remote using https? It seems as though it may be waiting for credentials and not properly prompting for them. Maybe try switching the remote to use ssh.

Comment: @janders223 thanks switching the remote to use ssh worked.

Answer (score 4):

I rarely ever run `:Gpush` on its own, so maybe try this:

`:Gstatus`

in the new split view, use `-` to toggle which changes you want to stage for the commit, then use `cc` to commit.

After entering the commit message and save/quit, the split window shows unpushed commits; you can use `-` to push individual commits. The exact push line and parameters are shown in the command line to be confirmed.

YMMV - I'd be curious what you make of this workflow.

Comment: Cool. I've been using `fugitive` for a while, and didn't know that. How do you even know that `-` pushes individual commits? I couldn't find it anywhere in the docs.

Answer (score 3):

Quote from vim-fugitive `README`:

> FAQ Why can't I enter my password when I :Gpush?
>
> It is highly recommended to use SSH keys or credentials caching to
>   avoid entering your password on every upstream interaction. If this
>   isn't an option, the official solution is to use the core.askPass Git
>   option to request the password via a GUI. Fugitive will configure this
>   for you automatically if you have ssh-askpass or git-gui installed;
>   otherwise it's your responsibility to set this up.
>
> As an absolute last resort, you can invoke :Git --paginate push.
>   Fugitive recognizes the pagination request and fires up a :terminal,
>   which allows for interactive password entry.

So, in your case, there are two possible solutions:

1. Use `:Git --paginate push`
2. Switch to ssh and authenticate with a key

Comment: I'm getting the same error even with the SSH key configured.